# Ability to set up multiple spies on the same method

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, promise, jasmine, spyon

We are trying to do unit testing with Jasmine to isolate a method or component that we need to test and see how it behaves under a variety of circumstances.

```js
return Promise.resolve(referenceObject()) //afraid this might execute out of order so force it inside promise chain.
           .then(() => this._apiClient.postRequest('putquestions', requestParametersPutSamples, questionInfo))
           .then(() => this._apiClient.postRequest('putitems', requestParametersPutNewSamples, { item: itemInfo }))
           .then((res: Array<any>) => this.expectEachResponseToBeOk(res));
   }
```

We are using spyOn for the existing methods as shown in the code above.
We have forced it inside a promise chain because this might execute out of order.

Any ideas on how can we spyOn on the same method which has been called twice but with different parameters?

Thanks.